# Android Studio; tools.jar error; Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

Whenever I run `./studio.sh` I get

```
JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

I have edited `/etc/environment` and appended it with

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

or

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

or

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java8
```

Whenever I check if JDK is installed correctly with

```
dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

I get

```
ii  gcj-4.8-jdk                                          4.8.4-1ubuntu15                            amd64        GCJ and Classpath development tools for Java(TM)
ii  openjdk-7-jdk:amd64                                  7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1                amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-7-jre:amd64                                  7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1                amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64                         7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1                amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  oracle-java8-installer                               8u51+8u51arm-1~webupd8~0                   all          Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8
ii  oracle-java9-installer                               9b74+9b74arm-1~webupd8~0                   all          Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 9
ii  oracle-java9-set-default                             9b74+9b74arm-1~webupd8~0                   all          Set Oracle JDK 9 as default Java
```

I have been googling for this problem for a few days now, but apparently there isn't a good solution.

Any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your system doesn't have `oracle-java7` why did you edit `JAVA_HOME` so?

Currently yours have `oracle-java8` and `oracle-java9` or `openjdk-7`.

I don't know that Android and Android Studio can compile with Java 9 by now.

I think you had better set the `oracle-java8` as default jdk by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and set `JAVA_HOME` as `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.

It may helps you.

Comment: So i did the above, but the problem persists.

Comment: Hm... For your information, there is `tools.jar` in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib` on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yes. I have already seen that. But unfortuantely it continues to show the same error.